# LinearAlloc exceeded capacity after signing app

Tags: android, dex

When i start my app with my IDE on an old devive htc desire s with android 2.3.x it deploys fine, but when i download it from hokeyapp or from google play it get the error

> ERROR/dalvikvm(21799): LinearAlloc exceeded capacity (5242880), last=80

the app is not installable when signed with my key, but when started vie IDE (signed with debug key) it is installable.
What is the difference between this signing ?

Here the Stacktrace

```
        10-15 13:18:39.489: DEBUG/View(9540): onTouchEvent: viewFlags: 0x18004401
    10-15 13:18:39.489: DEBUG/View(9540): onTouchEvent: isFocusable: true, isFocusableInTouchMode: false, isFocused: false; focusTaken: false
    10-15 13:18:39.489: INFO/ActivityManager(1375): Starting activity: Intent { dat=file:///mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/files/scratch/apk/android-app-2.2.apk cmp=com.android.packageinstaller/.InstallAppProgress (has extras) } from pid 9540
    10-15 13:18:39.549: WARN/InstallAppProgress(9540): Replacing package:de.mobile
    10-15 13:18:39.559: DEBUG/ATRecorder(9540): com.htc.autotest.dlib.RecordEngine in loader dalvik.system.DexClassLoader@405388f8
    10-15 13:18:39.559: DEBUG/WindowManagerImpl(9540): addView, new view, mViews[1]: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@405414f0
    10-15 13:18:39.609: VERBOSE/WindowManager(1375): Starting animation in AppWindowToken{40df0cf8 token=HistoryRecord{40a05f20 com.android.packageinstaller/.PackageInstallerActivity}} @ 66494745
    10-15 13:18:39.609: VERBOSE/WindowManager(1375): Starting animation in AppWindowToken{40d4ac50 token=HistoryRecord{40a3b698 com.android.packageinstaller/.InstallAppProgress}} @ 66494745
    10-15 13:18:39.619: INFO/keystore(1270): uid: 1000 action: e -> 7 state: 2 -> 2 retry: 4
    10-15 13:18:39.639: INFO/keystore(1270): uid: 1000 action: e -> 7 state: 2 -> 2 retry: 4
    10-15 13:18:39.639: INFO/ActivityManager(1375): Start proc com.android.defcontainer for service com.android.defcontainer/.DefaultContainerService: pid=22536 uid=10095 gids={1015, 2001}
    10-15 13:18:39.639: VERBOSE/ActivityManager(1375): Checking to restart com.android.packageinstaller.InstallAppProgress: changed=0x0, handles=0xa0
            oldConfig={ scale=1.0 imsi=262/7 loc=en_DE touch=3 keys=1/1/2 nav=1/1 orien=1 layout=34 uiMode=17 seq=25 skin=default fontsize=3}
            newConfig={ scale=1.0 imsi=262/7 loc=en_DE touch=3 keys=1/1/2 nav=1/1 orien=1 layout=34 uiMode=17 seq=25 skin=default fontsize=3}
    10-15 13:18:39.639: DEBUG/ActivityManager(1375): destroyActivityLocked, r=HistoryRecord{40a05f20 com.android.packageinstaller/.PackageInstallerActivity}
    10-15 13:18:39.639: VERBOSE/ActivityManager(1375): destroyActivityLocked, dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
    10-15 13:18:39.639: VERBOSE/ActivityManager(1375): destroyActivityLocked, java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:745)
    10-15 13:18:39.639: VERBOSE/ActivityManager(1375): destroyActivityLocked, com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.destroyActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3332)
    10-15 13:18:39.639: VERBOSE/ActivityManager(1375): destroyActivityLocked, com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.activityIdleInternal(ActivityStack.java:3010)
    10-15 13:18:39.639: VERBOSE/ActivityManager(1375): destroyActivityLocked, com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.activityIdle(ActivityManagerService.java:4410)
    10-15 13:18:39.649: VERBOSE/ActivityManager(1375): destroyActivityLocked, android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:371)
    10-15 13:18:39.649: VERBOSE/ActivityManager(1375): destroyActivityLocked, com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:1642)
    10-15 13:18:39.649: VERBOSE/ActivityManager(1375): destroyActivityLocked, android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:320)
    10-15 13:18:39.649: VERBOSE/ActivityManager(1375): destroyActivityLocked, dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
    10-15 13:18:39.659: DEBUG/WindowManagerImpl(9540): finishRemoveViewLocked, mViews[0]: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4051fe60
    10-15 13:18:39.759: INFO/com.dropbox.android.util.ae(22507): File not modified: /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/files/scratch/17a1c/8aad3f9a
    10-15 13:18:39.779: VERBOSE/WindowManager(1375): Finished animation in AppWindowToken{40d4ac50 token=HistoryRecord{40a3b698 com.android.packageinstaller/.InstallAppProgress}} @ 66494925
    10-15 13:18:39.779: INFO/ActivityManager(1375): Displayed com.android.packageinstaller/.InstallAppProgress: +282ms
    10-15 13:18:39.779: VERBOSE/WindowManager(1375): Finished animation in AppWindowToken{40df0cf8 token=HistoryRecord{40a05f20 com.android.packageinstaller/.PackageInstallerActivity}} @ 66494925
    10-15 13:18:39.789: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22536): GC_EXPLICIT freed 49K, 48% free 2847K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 41ms
    10-15 13:18:39.789: WARN/ActivityManager(1375): No content provider found for:
    10-15 13:18:40.159: DEBUG/skia(1375): purging 64K from font cache [7 entries]
    10-15 13:18:40.380: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1375): GC_EXPLICIT freed 481K, 44% free 10090K/17735K, external 968K/1480K, paused 221ms
    10-15 13:18:40.440: INFO/com.dropbox.android.util.ae(22507): File not modified: /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/files/scratch/17a1c/8aad3f9a
    10-15 13:18:40.440: WARN/ActivityManager(1375): No content provider found for:
    10-15 13:18:40.450: DEBUG/PackageParser(1375): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl-1146412655.tmp
    10-15 13:18:40.660: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1375): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 947K, 40% free 10783K/17735K, external 912K/1424K, paused 106ms
    10-15 13:18:40.670: DEBUG/StatusBarPolicy(1512): Network Type: 8
    10-15 13:18:40.790: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1375): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 271K, 39% free 10824K/17735K, external 912K/1424K, paused 109ms
    10-15 13:18:41.140: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1375): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 568K, 34% free 11721K/17735K, external 912K/1424K, paused 129ms
    10-15 13:18:41.441: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1375): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1515K, 32% free 12196K/17735K, external 912K/1424K, paused 3ms+8ms
    10-15 13:18:41.731: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1375): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2012K, 32% free 12225K/17735K, external 912K/1424K, paused 4ms+7ms
    10-15 13:18:42.001: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1375): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2032K, 32% free 12235K/17735K, external 912K/1424K, paused 3ms+7ms
    10-15 13:18:42.271: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1375): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2040K, 31% free 12242K/17735K, external 912K/1424K, paused 3ms+7ms
    10-15 13:18:42.542: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1375): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1981K, 31% free 12305K/17735K, external 912K/1424K, paused 3ms+8ms
    10-15 13:18:42.802: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1375): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2081K, 31% free 12270K/17735K, external 912K/1424K, paused 3ms+7ms
    10-15 13:18:43.443: DEBUG/PowerManagerService(1375): New lightsensor value:640, lcdValue:126
    10-15 13:18:43.443: DEBUG/PowerManagerService(1375): lightSensorChangedLocked, buttonValue >= 0, mPowerState = 3
    10-15 13:18:43.483: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1375): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2025K, 31% free 12288K/17735K, external 912K/1424K, paused 3ms+7ms
    10-15 13:18:43.773: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1375): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1986K, 31% free 12356K/17735K, external 912K/1424K, paused 3ms+7ms
    10-15 13:18:43.833: INFO/PackageManager(1375): Removing non-system package:de.mobile
    10-15 13:18:43.833: DEBUG/Process(1375): killProcess, pid=22142
    10-15 13:18:43.833: INFO/keystore(1270): uid: 1000 action: g -> 2 state: 2 -> 2 retry: 4
    10-15 13:18:43.833: INFO/ActivityManager(1375): Force stopping package de.mobile uid=10138
    10-15 13:18:43.843: DEBUG/Process(1375): dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
    10-15 13:18:43.843: DEBUG/Process(1375): java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:745)
    10-15 13:18:43.843: DEBUG/Process(1375): android.os.Process.killProcess(Process.java:797)
    10-15 13:18:43.843: DEBUG/Process(1375): com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.removeProcessLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:4088)
    10-15 13:18:43.843: DEBUG/Process(1375): com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.killPackageProcessesLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:3966)
    10-15 13:18:43.843: DEBUG/Process(1375): com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.forceStopPackageLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:4002)
    10-15 13:18:43.843: DEBUG/Process(1375): com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.access$400(ActivityManagerService.java:212)
    10-15 13:18:43.843: DEBUG/Process(1375): com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$2.handleMessage(ActivityManagerService.java:1293)
    10-15 13:18:43.843: DEBUG/Process(1375): android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    10-15 13:18:43.843: DEBUG/Process(1375): android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
    10-15 13:18:43.843: DEBUG/Process(1375): com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$AThread.run(ActivityManagerService.java:1497)
    10-15 13:18:43.843: INFO/Process(1375): Sending signal. PID: 22142 SIG: 9
    10-15 13:18:43.843: INFO/keystore(1270): uid: 1000 action: e -> 7 state: 2 -> 2 retry: 4
    10-15 13:18:43.903: WARN/ContentService(1375): binderDied() at ObserverNode name com.urbanairship.push.PUSH_ENABLED
    10-15 13:18:43.913: WARN/ContentService(1375): binderDied() at ObserverNode name com.urbanairship.push.APP_VERSION
    10-15 13:18:43.913: WARN/ContentService(1375): binderDied() at ObserverNode name com.urbanairship.push.LAST_APID_REGISTRATION_TIME
    10-15 13:18:43.913: WARN/ContentService(1375): binderDied() at ObserverNode name com.urbanairship.push.APID
    10-15 13:18:43.913: WARN/ContentService(1375): binderDied() at ObserverNode name com.urbanairship.push.BOX_OFFICE_SECRET
    10-15 13:18:43.913: WARN/ContentService(1375): binderDied() at ObserverNode name com.urbanairship.push.DEVICE_ID
    10-15 13:18:43.913: WARN/ContentService(1375): binderDied() at ObserverNode name com.urbanairship.push.GCM_REGISTRATION_ID_KEY
    10-15 13:18:43.913: WARN/ContentService(1375): binderDied() at ObserverNode name com.urbanairship.push.APID_READY
    10-15 13:18:43.913: WARN/ContentService(1375): binderDied() at ObserverNode name com.urbanairship.analytics.LAST_SEND
    10-15 13:18:43.913: WARN/ContentService(1375): binderDied() at ObserverNode name com.urbanairship.push.APID_UPDATE_NEEDED
    10-15 13:18:43.953: DEBUG/PackageManager(1375): Scanning package de.mobile
    10-15 13:18:43.953: INFO/keystore(1270): uid: 1000 action: g -> 2 state: 2 -> 2 retry: 4
    10-15 13:18:43.953: DEBUG/installd(1269): DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/de.mobile-2.apk' ---
    10-15 13:18:43.953: INFO/PackageManager(1375): Package de.mobile codePath changed from /data/app/de.mobile-1.apk to /data/app/de.mobile-2.apk; Retaining data and using new
    10-15 13:18:43.953: INFO/PackageManager(1375): Linking native library dir for /data/app/de.mobile-2.apk
    10-15 13:18:44.544: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22544): creating instr width table
    10-15 13:18:45.955: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22544): DexOpt: 'Lorg/apache/http/HttpEntity;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
    10-15 13:18:45.955: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22544): DexOpt: 'Lorg/apache/http/entity/AbstractHttpEntity;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
    10-15 13:18:45.955: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22544): DexOpt: 'Lorg/apache/http/HttpMessage;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
    10-15 13:18:45.955: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22544): DexOpt: 'Lorg/apache/http/message/AbstractHttpMessage;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
    10-15 13:18:45.955: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22544): DexOpt: 'Lorg/apache/http/HttpRequest;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
    10-15 13:18:45.955: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22544): DexOpt: 'Lorg/apache/http/client/methods/HttpUriRequest;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
    10-15 13:18:45.955: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22544): DexOpt: 'Lorg/apache/http/client/methods/AbortableHttpRequest;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
    10-15 13:18:45.955: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22544): DexOpt: 'Lorg/apache/http/client/methods/HttpRequestBase;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
    10-15 13:18:45.955: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22544): DexOpt: 'Lorg/apache/http/HttpEntityEnclosingRequest;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
    10-15 13:18:45.955: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22544): DexOpt: 'Lorg/apache/http/client/methods/HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
    10-15 13:18:45.955: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22544): DexOpt: 'Lorg/apache/http/conn/scheme/SocketFactory;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
    10-15 13:18:45.955: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22544): DexOpt: 'Lorg/apache/http/conn/scheme/LayeredSocketFactory;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
    10-15 13:18:45.955: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22544): DexOpt: 'Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLSocketFactory;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
    10-15 13:18:46.085: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1559): GC_EXPLICIT freed 68K, 51% free 4338K/8775K, external 8341K/10369K, paused 393ms
    10-15 13:18:46.105: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22544): DexOpt: 'Lorg/apache/http/HttpRequestInterceptor;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
    10-15 13:18:46.105: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22544): DexOpt: 'Lorg/apache/http/HttpResponseInterceptor;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
    10-15 13:18:46.105: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22544): DexOpt: 'Lorg/apache/http/entity/HttpEntityWrapper;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
    10-15 13:18:46.105: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22544): DexOpt: 'Lorg/apache/http/client/CookieStore;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
    10-15 13:18:46.105: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22544): DexOpt: 'Lorg/apache/http/client/HttpRequestRetryHandler;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
    10-15 13:18:46.125: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22544): DexOpt: 'Lorg/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
    10-15 13:18:46.215: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22544): DexOpt: 'Lorg/apache/commons/codec/Decoder;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
    10-15 13:18:46.215: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22544): DexOpt: ...

.............

'Lorg/apache/http/protocol/RequestExpectContinue;': multiple definitions
    10-15 13:18:48.878: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22544): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/protocol/RequestTargetHost;': multiple definitions
    10-15 13:18:48.878: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22544): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/protocol/RequestUserAgent;': multiple definitions
    10-15 13:18:48.878: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22544): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/protocol/ResponseConnControl;': multiple definitions
    10-15 13:18:48.878: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22544): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/protocol/ResponseContent;': multiple definitions
    10-15 13:18:48.878: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22544): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/protocol/ResponseDate;': multiple definitions
    10-15 13:18:48.878: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22544): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/protocol/ResponseServer;': multiple definitions
    10-15 13:18:48.878: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22544): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/protocol/SyncBasicHttpContext;': multiple definitions
    10-15 13:18:48.878: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22544): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/protocol/UriPatternMatcher;': multiple definitions
    10-15 13:18:48.878: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22544): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/util/ByteArrayBuffer;': multiple definitions
    10-15 13:18:48.878: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22544): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/util/CharArrayBuffer;': multiple definitions
    10-15 13:18:48.878: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22544): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/util/EncodingUtils;': multiple definitions
    10-15 13:18:48.878: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22544): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/util/EntityUtils;': multiple definitions
    10-15 13:18:48.878: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22544): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/util/ExceptionUtils;': multiple definitions
    10-15 13:18:48.878: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22544): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/util/LangUtils;': multiple definitions
    10-15 13:18:48.878: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22544): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/util/VersionInfo;': multiple definitions
    10-15 13:18:49.148: ERROR/dalvikvm(22544): LinearAlloc exceeded capacity (5242880), last=2028
    10-15 13:18:49.148: ERROR/dalvikvm(22544): VM aborting
    10-15 13:18:49.549: INFO/DEBUG(1263): debuggerd: 2013-10-15 13:18:49
    10-15 13:18:49.549: INFO/DEBUG(1263): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
    10-15 13:18:49.549: INFO/DEBUG(1263): Build fingerprint: 'o2_uk/htc_saga/saga:2.3.5/GRJ90/181069.1:user/release-keys'
    10-15 13:18:49.549: INFO/DEBUG(1263): pid: 22544, tid: 22544  >>> /system/bin/dexopt <<<
    10-15 13:18:49.549: INFO/DEBUG(1263): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadd00d
    10-15 13:18:49.559: INFO/DEBUG(1263): r0 fffffe78  r1 deadd00d  r2 00000026  r3 00000000
    10-15 13:18:49.559: INFO/DEBUG(1263): r4 800a7678  r5 004ffa5c  r6 0050024c  r7 0001a984
    10-15 13:18:49.559: INFO/DEBUG(1263): r8 000007ec  r9 00000027  10 00000001  fp 0000401e
    10-15 13:18:49.559: INFO/DEBUG(1263): ip 800a7788  sp be8d7648  lr afd19c11  pc 80046b24  cpsr 20000030
    10-15 13:18:49.559: INFO/DEBUG(1263): d0  74726f6261204d69  d1  646564656563786e
    10-15 13:18:49.559: INFO/DEBUG(1263): d2  642f6c6d782f7867  d3  2f6570797461740a
    10-15 13:18:49.559: INFO/DEBUG(1263): d4  6e6f736b63616a2f  d5  7365442f70616d2f
    10-15 13:18:49.559: INFO/DEBUG(1263): d6  617a696c61697265  d7  746e6f436e6f6974
    10-15 13:18:49.559: INFO/DEBUG(1263): d8  00003c7b749b7078  d9  0000000000000000
    10-15 13:18:49.559: INFO/DEBUG(1263): d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
    10-15 13:18:49.559: INFO/DEBUG(1263): d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
    10-15 13:18:49.559: INFO/DEBUG(1263): d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
    10-15 13:18:49.559: INFO/DEBUG(1263): d16 0000000000000000  d17 0000000000000000
    10-15 13:18:49.559: INFO/DEBUG(1263): d18 0000000000000000  d19 0000000000000000
    10-15 13:18:49.559: INFO/DEBUG(1263): d20 0000000000000000  d21 0000000000000000
    10-15 13:18:49.559: INFO/DEBUG(1263): d22 0000000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
    10-15 13:18:49.559: INFO/DEBUG(1263): d24 0000000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
    10-15 13:18:49.559: INFO/DEBUG(1263): d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
    10-15 13:18:49.559: INFO/DEBUG(1263): d28 0000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
    10-15 13:18:49.559: INFO/DEBUG(1263): d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
    10-15 13:18:49.559: INFO/DEBUG(1263): scr 00000010
    10-15 13:18:49.569: INFO/DEBUG(1263): #00  pc 00046b24  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    10-15 13:18:49.569: INFO/DEBUG(1263): #01  pc 0004ed4a  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    10-15 13:18:49.569: INFO/DEBUG(1263): #02  pc 0006bcb6  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    10-15 13:18:49.569: INFO/DEBUG(1263): #03  pc 0006bf74  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    10-15 13:18:49.569: INFO/DEBUG(1263): #04  pc 0006c7b4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    10-15 13:18:49.569: INFO/DEBUG(1263): #05  pc 0006c9fa  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    10-15 13:18:49.569: INFO/DEBUG(1263): #06  pc 0006c222  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    10-15 13:18:49.579: INFO/DEBUG(1263): #07  pc 0005deac  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    10-15 13:18:49.579: INFO/DEBUG(1263): #08  pc 00059f96  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    10-15 13:18:49.579: INFO/DEBUG(1263): #09  pc 0005c142  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    10-15 13:18:49.579: INFO/DEBUG(1263): #10  pc 0005c37e  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    10-15 13:18:49.579: INFO/DEBUG(1263): #11  pc 0005dd50  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    10-15 13:18:49.579: INFO/DEBUG(1263): #12  pc 0005dda2  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    10-15 13:18:49.589: INFO/DEBUG(1263): #13  pc 0005cbce  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    10-15 13:18:49.589: INFO/DEBUG(1263): #14  pc 0005cc7c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    10-15 13:18:49.589: INFO/DEBUG(1263): #15  pc 0005cd80  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    10-15 13:18:49.589: INFO/DEBUG(1263): code around pc:
    10-15 13:18:49.589: INFO/DEBUG(1263): 80046b04 447a4479 f7d04c0b 2000eea6 efb0f7d0
    10-15 13:18:49.589: INFO/DEBUG(1263): 80046b14 447c4809 6bdb5823 4798b103 22264902
    10-15 13:18:49.589: INFO/DEBUG(1263): 80046b24 f7d1700a bf00e824 deadd00d 00044627
    10-15 13:18:49.589: INFO/DEBUG(1263): 80046b34 0004624c 00060b5e fffffe78 4b09b40e
    10-15 13:18:49.589: INFO/DEBUG(1263): 80046b44 4c09b517 aa05447b f852591b 6b5b1b04
    10-15 13:18:49.599: INFO/DEBUG(1263): code around lr:
    10-15 13:18:49.599: INFO/DEBUG(1263): afd19bf0 4a0e4b0d e92d447b 589c41f0 26004680
    10-15 13:18:49.599: INFO/DEBUG(1263): afd19c00 686768a5 f9b5e006 b113300c 47c04628
    10-15 13:18:49.599: INFO/DEBUG(1263): afd19c10 35544306 37fff117 6824d5f5 d1ef2c00
    10-15 13:18:49.599: INFO/DEBUG(1263): afd19c20 e8bd4630 bf0081f0 00028830 ffffff64
    10-15 13:18:49.599: INFO/DEBUG(1263): afd19c30 b086b570 f602fb01 9004460c a804a901
    10-15 13:18:49.599: INFO/DEBUG(1263): stack:
    10-15 13:18:49.599: INFO/DEBUG(1263): be8d7608  800acdc8
    10-15 13:18:49.599: INFO/DEBUG(1263): be8d760c  00000001
    10-15 13:18:49.599: INFO/DEBUG(1263): be8d7610  402133f0
    10-15 13:18:49.599: INFO/DEBUG(1263): be8d7614  be8d76a0
    10-15 13:18:49.599: INFO/DEBUG(1263): be8d7618  afd4362c
    10-15 13:18:49.599: INFO/DEBUG(1263): be8d761c  afd435d8
    10-15 13:18:49.599: INFO/DEBUG(1263): be8d7620  00000000
    10-15 13:18:49.599: INFO/DEBUG(1263): be8d7624  afd19c11  /system/lib/libc.so
    10-15 13:18:49.599: INFO/DEBUG(1263): be8d7628  00060b5e
    10-15 13:18:49.599: INFO/DEBUG(1263): be8d762c  004ffa5c
    10-15 13:18:49.599: INFO/DEBUG(1263): be8d7630  0050024c
    10-15 13:18:49.599: INFO/DEBUG(1263): be8d7634  0001a984
    10-15 13:18:49.599: INFO/DEBUG(1263): be8d7638  000007ec
    10-15 13:18:49.609: INFO/DEBUG(1263): be8d763c  afd18d09  /system/lib/libc.so
    10-15 13:18:49.609: INFO/DEBUG(1263): be8d7640  df002777
    10-15 13:18:49.609: INFO/DEBUG(1263): be8d7644  e3a070ad
    10-15 13:18:49.609: INFO/DEBUG(1263): #00 be8d7648  0001a980
    10-15 13:18:49.609: INFO/DEBUG(1263): be8d764c  8004ed4f  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    10-15 13:18:49.609: INFO/DEBUG(1263): #01 be8d7650  000007ec
    10-15 13:18:49.609: INFO/DEBUG(1263): be8d7654  000007ec
    10-15 13:18:49.609: INFO/DEBUG(1263): be8d7658  42a8a4ab
    10-15 13:18:49.609: INFO/DEBUG(1263): be8d765c  4024e2c0
    10-15 13:18:49.609: INFO/DEBUG(1263): be8d7660  0001f600
    10-15 13:18:49.609: INFO/DEBUG(1263): be8d7664  427187f8
    10-15 13:18:49.609: INFO/DEBUG(1263): be8d7668  00000000
    10-15 13:18:49.609: INFO/DEBUG(1263): be8d766c  00000027
    10-15 13:18:49.609: INFO/DEBUG(1263): be8d7670  00000001
    10-15 13:18:49.609: INFO/DEBUG(1263): be8d7674  8006bcbb  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    10-15 13:18:49.629: WARN/installd(1269): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/de.mobile-2.apk' --- status=0x000b, process failed
    10-15 13:18:49.629: ERROR/installd(1269): dexopt failed on '/data/dalvik-cache/data@app@de.mobile-2.apk@classes.dex' res = 11
    10-15 13:18:49.639: WARN/PackageManager(1375): Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/de.mobile-2.apk
```

Comment: Can you post the full log? Any warnings before that? Also, is that (21799) your process or some other piece of the framework?

Comment: Okay. That's actually useful. Are you trying to ship your own Apache HTTP Client? Dexopt seems to be failing while trying to verify your classes. This usually happens if 1) you have too many classes, in which case you should split them in multiple .dex files or 2) you have too many methods.

Comment: i read about this limitations, but what i don't get is why i don't get the error when installing the app from the IDE with the debug key signing

Comment: No idea. It could be that the signature check uses LinearAlloc space and the production keys (being two - yours + one from the store) trigger the error.